# codeigniter: call Index Method from another method

Tags: codeigniter

I am new in `CodeIgniter`. I am getting a problem. My procedure seems logical but it would not work!

I have a controller: `User`

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()   {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');  
    }

    public function index($slug = FALSE) {
        $data['title'] = "User List";
        if($slug === FALSE) {
            $data['user'] = $this->user_model->get_user();      
        } else {
            $data['user'] = $this->user_model->get_user($slug);      
        }    
        if (empty($data['user'])){
            show_404();
        }
        $this->load->library('table');        
        $this->load->view('user_view', $data);    
    }

    public function authen() {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');    

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'phone', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('login_form');
        } else {
            if($this->user_model->do_login()===TRUE) {
                $this->index();
            }      
            $this->authen();                   
        }
    }
}
```

The "authen" method is not working properly with its last conditions. Page does not redirect to controller.

Can anybody help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: `redirect('user')` it will redirect u to the controller user class

Comment: Thanks, It works. But why not the $this->index() not working? In fact several google sites is saying so..

Comment: Try to check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723883/redirect-with-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$this->index();
```

try this

```
header('Location:http://myipaddress/mysite/user');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are try to load the login page in case there is any authentication error.

For for this you will need to bring user to the login page again.

use redirect('user/login'); and store the error message in session flash.

or display validation errors..

you cannot call controller from a controller. as $this->index();