# Page redirection in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a newbie to Codeigniter. As part of studying it, I created a form which inserts data to the database. After insertion it is not redirecting properly to the form view page (formvalidation.php).

**Form Action**

```
    public function submitform()
    {
        $formdata['username']=$this->input->post('username');
        $formdata['address']=$this->input->post('address');
        $formdata['state']=$this->input->post('state');
        $formdata['country']=$this->input->post('country');
        $data['state']=$this->getstatearray();
        $data['country']=$this->getcountries();
        if($this->userprofile_model->setdata($formdata)=='success')
        {
            $this->load->view('formvalidation/formvalidation',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('formvalidation/formvalidation',$data);
        }
    }
```

**Form view page (formvalidation.php)**

```
echo form_open('formvalidation/submitform'); 
echo form_input('username');
echo "<br>".form_textarea("address");
echo "<br>".form_dropdown('state',$state);
echo "<br>";
echo form_dropdown('country',$country);
echo "<br><br>".form_submit('submit','Submit');
echo form_close();
```

**Model (userprofile_model.php)**

```
class userprofile_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function setdata($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('userprofile',$data);  
        if($this->db->affected_rows()>0)
        {
            echo "success";
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "fail";
        }
    }
}
```

Now the value is getting inserted into the database. But after insertion I want to redirect it to the url http://www.example.com/codeigniter/index.php/formvalidation/. But instead, it is now redirecting to http://www.example.com/codeigniter/index.php/formvalidation/submitform where *submitform* is the form action method.

How can I solve this problem? I tried with putting `exit;` after the page redirect function. But it won't work. Please help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723883/redirect-with-codeigniter

Answer (score 3):

yes it will, because there is no redirect code. When the form is submitted your `submitform` function is executed and in that function you are loading the view. So if you want to redirect
to something else you must use the `redirect()` function.

```
public function submitform()
    {
        $formdata['username']=$this->input->post('username');
        $formdata['address']=$this->input->post('address');
        $formdata['state']=$this->input->post('state');
        $formdata['country']=$this->input->post('country');
        $data['state']=$this->getstatearray();
        $data['country']=$this->getcountries();
        if($this->userprofile_model->setdata($formdata)=='success'){
                 redirect("Your URL");
        }
        else{
                redirect("Your URL");
        }
    }
```

Also you must properly sanitize the user input. You must validate your form inputs before passing it to model. You can find more info [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

Answer (score 1):

First Load the view page in controller index function.

`function index()`
`{`
`$this->load->view('v_bank_master');`
`}`

Then in model page,  after insertion done. give the below code.

`redirect('give your controller page name here','refresh');`

Your page will now redirect to the view page after insertion.

Hope it will help you...

Answer (score 0):

I use redirect('yourControllerName', 'refresh').

Read more here: [Redirect()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Answer (score 0):

After insertion give the below code

```
redirect('controller_name/function_name');
```