# CodeIgniter 4 redirect function not working

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

After logout, I tried to redirect for the home page. I tried to few ways, but not redirected.

```
class User extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        helper('url');
    }
```

for the logout function. I used three ways

```
redirect('/');
```

or

```
header("Location:".base_url());
```

or

```
route_to('/');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723883/redirect-with-codeigniter)

Comment: @MartinDimitrov I tried this already. In CodeIgniter 4 not working

Comment: I found redirect() must be called before any actual output is sent. 
redirect() ulimately calls the php function header().

Answer (score 32, accepted):

as per CI 4

**use**

```
return redirect()->to('url');
```

if you are using route then use

```
return redirect()->route('named_route');
```

Comment: you are right but how we can redirect to particular controller like we can do in CI 3 redirect('conroller/method') ?

I don't think we should do it like 

return redirect()->to(base_url().'/public/conroller/method','refresh'); ?

Comment: @Samiul plz can you show the code, why not working?

Comment: Anyone who wants to redirect a route forcefully, You can do it by 
`redirect('<route>','location',304)->send();` Redirect function creates `RedirectResponse ` object which is consumed by CI runtime and the class is extended upto MessageInterface. Because only controller methods are excepted to create Messages i.e. Response and Request objects, it defaults to creating proper response object which is built and then proper send method is called. 
Hope this helps anyone who is stuck with documentation.

Comment: how to remove 'index.php' after redirection?

Answer (score 4):

I use this and it works

```
return redirect()->to(site_url());
```

Answer (score 2):

In codeigniter 4 redirect()->to() returns a RedirectResponse object, which you need to return from your controller to do the redirect.

for ex.

```
class Home extends BaseController {
    public function index() {
        return redirect()->to('https://example.com');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its worth saying that unlike the former CI3 `redirect()` function this one must be called from within a Controller. It won't work for example within a Library.

**Update 2021**

It is in fact possible to do this! Simply check that the returned response is an object and return it instead. So if a library returns a RedirectResponse, check it using the following code and return if applicable.

```
if (!empty($log) && is_object($log)){
    return $log;
}
```

You could of course do `get_class()` to make sure the object is a type of `RedirectResponse` if there is any possibility of another object being returned.

Answer (score 1):

If you using unnamed route:

```
$this->response->redirect(site_url('/user'));
```

'/user': It is my controller name. You can also used controller/function name.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to CI4.  In my case, I had to properly set **$baseURL in App.php**.  For example, if the port is set incorrectly in your local development, it will just hang.

eg. `public $baseURL = 'http://localhost:8888/';`

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the documentation

// Go back to the previous page
return redirect()->back();

// Go to specific URI
return redirect()->to('/admin');

// Go to a named route
return redirect()->route('named_route');

// Keep the old input values upon redirect so they can be used by the `old()` function
return redirect()->back()->withInput();

// Set a flash message
return redirect()->back()->with('foo', 'message');

// Copies all cookies from global response instance
return redirect()->back()->withCookies();

// Copies all headers from the global response instance
return redirect()->back()->withHeaders();

Comment: This is an answer to a already answered question from a couple of years ago. 
It's badly formatted and the first line is: "Please look at the documentation"

It doesn't really help the op.

Answer (score -1):

If you find:

> `{0, string} route cannot be found while reverse-routing`

This error:

> `Please Go to system\HTTP\RedirectResponse Line no 91 :`

Change:

```php
throw HTTPException::forInvalidRedirectRoute($route);
```

To:

```php
return $this->redirect(site_url('/Home'));  
(dashboard after login)
```

Answer (score -5):

The redirect statement in code igniter sends the user to the specified web page using a redirect header statement.
This statement resides in the URL helper which is loaded in the following way:

```
 $this->load->helper('url');
```

The redirect function loads a local URI specified in the first parameter of the function call and built using the options specified in your config file.

The second parameter allows the developer to use different HTTP commands to perform the redirect "location" or "refresh".

According to the Code Igniter documentation: "Location is faster, but on Windows servers it can sometimes be a problem."

Example:

```
if ($user_logged_in === FALSE)
{
 redirect('/account/login', 'refresh');
}
```

**Original Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/725200/5700401**

Comment: CI4 has already autoloaded it by default. It won't work here.